# Improving JOIN with sub-query

Tags: mysql, query-performance, join, subquery, mariadb-10.5

I capture Users who comment on the Articles of other Users, as

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO AuthorCommentators (AuthorID,CommentatorID,Freq) 
    SELECT AuthorID,CommentatorID,C FROM 
        (SELECT b.UserID AS AuthorID,c.UserID AS CommentatorID,COUNT(*) AS C 
            FROM ArticleComments a  
                JOIN ArticleMap b ON a.ArticleID=b.ArticleID 
                JOIN CommentMap c ON a.CommentID=c.CommentID 
                GROUP BY b.UserID,c.UserID
         ) c 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Freq=c.C
```

but since `ArticleComments` table is too large, the query is slow.

Is there any way to improve this query?

The tables are simple,

```
CREATE TABLE AuthorCommentators
(
AuthorID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
CommentatorID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
Freq mediumint(7) unsigned,
INDEX(CommentatorID),
INDEX(Freq),
PRIMARY KEY(AuthorID,CommentatorID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE ArticleComments
(
ArticleID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
CommentID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
INDEX(CommentID),
PRIMARY KEY(ArticleID,CommentID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE ArticleMap
(
ArticleID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
UserID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
INDEX(UserID),
PRIMARY KEY(ArticleID,UserID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE CommentMap
(
CommentID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
UserID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
INDEX(UserID),
PRIMARY KEY(CommentID,UserID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Since both `Articles` and `Comments` can have multiple authors, I have to normalise the architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a subtotal every day (or some other convenient unit of time).  Put those subtotals in a "summary table".

Or run your IODKU only from where you left off last time, not from the start.  Of course, it would need a small change;

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Freq = Freq + c.C
```

More on summary tables: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables